# Distribute different objects into identical bins

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 6 identical pots and 26 different coins. In how many ways can we distribute these coins into pots where any pot can contain any number of coins.

For small numbers like 3 pots and 4 coins, it was easy to do because I was manually able to list the configurations possible and solve the sum like (4,0,0) , (3,1,0) etc.

How about this sum?

Comment: 26 **different** coins? You actually mean identical?

Comment: @OveAhlman Nope. All different coins. You can consider them as C1,C2...C26.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy answer.  If the pots were distinct there would be $6^{26}$ ways to distribute the coins.  When we make the pots identical we are counting the same distribution many ways.  If the numbers of coins in each pot are different, we have counted this configuration $6!=720$ times.  If we put all the coins in the same pot we have only counted it $6$ times because we just have that many choices for which pot to use.

Comment: Generally the overcount is $6!$ divided by the factorials of the numbers of matching pots, so the partition $(6,6,6,3,3,2)$ would be counted $\frac {6!}{3!2!}$ times.  You would have to find all the partitions of $26$ into at most $6$ pieces, compute the number of ways to generate that partition, then compute the overcount factor.

Comment: @RossMillikan Even I think the same.In my book actually it was 3 identical pots and 4 different coins and it was easy to solve. What if it would have been 6 identical pots and 26 **identical coins** ? Would it then be just counting number of unordered paritions in this case (bells number)?

Comment: How will stars and bars work in that case ? Consider 3 identical pots and 4 identical coins. By stars and bars, answer would be 15 but actually the answer is 4.

Comment: Yes stars and bars won't work. @Ross Millikan, can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

The number can be found by adding  Stirling numbers of the second kind, each corresponding to a different number of non-empty bins.$$ S(26,1)+S(26,2)+S(26,3)+S(26,4)+S(26,5)+S(26,6).$$ The Stirling numbers can be calculated by a simple recurrence relation - found  on Wikipedia.
(Answer modified after discussion - see comments.)

Comment: Nope. Stirling numbers of the second kind only count the non-empty partitions of a set. That is, $S(26, 6)$ will count only the number of ways in which you could divide 26 distinct coins into 6 pots without any pot being empty. The question clearly states that "any pot can contain any number of coins", so your answer misses the case where a pot is allowed to be empty

Comment: Yes thanks, I didn't read the question carefully enough. You would have to add the Stirling numbers for different numbers of non-empty pots.

Comment: That's a nice idea actually, and I think the correct answer. You should edit your answer.