# In how many ways can you place $12$ different toys in $3$ identical boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am a freshman studying Computer Science at a university, and currently struggling with some tasks from the Combinatorics part of the Discrete Math class. Any help would be appreciated.

*In how many ways can you place $12$ different toys in $3$ identical boxes?*

**My vision of solving this problem:**

For each toy there is $3$ boxes to put it into. $\implies 3^{12}$ possible combinations to place it.
Considering that the boxes are identical we have just counted doubles as well that should not be counted.
There is $3$ identical boxes $\implies$ they can be permuted $P_3 = 3!$ times for each combination of toys and these would actually correspond to the same combination.

*Hence, Solution*: $$\frac{3^{12}}{3!}$$ possible ways to place $12$ different toys in $3$ identical boxes.

I am not sure if it's really the $3!$ that I should be dividing them by and whether even I should do so. Does this solution make any sense?

Comment: Alas, the problem is not that simple.  This problem involves the use of [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: The arrangement "all $12$ in one box" only corresponds to $3$, not $6$, labeled-box arrangements. So you need to adjust for that ...

Comment: Hmm, we never reviewed "Stirling numbers of the second kind". So I guess I can't really use it in the process of solving this task.

Comment: Yes, indeed. $\frac{3^{11}}{3!} * \frac{3^1}{3} = \frac{3^{11}}{3!}$ then?

Comment: Similar question to yours - basically opposite of stars and bars https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532376/distribute-different-objects-into-identical-bins

Comment: @Treedye  I put in the details in the answer below. Split the labeled-box set into the $3$ with $2$ empties, and all the rest in the other piece. Mod out into identical-box arrangements on each of those two pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "all $12$ in one box" arrangement corresponds to $3$ labeled-box arrangements.

All other arrangements correspond to $6$ labeled-box arrangements (since the $3$ boxes all hold different contents in all of these).

The number of labeled-box arrangements is 3^12 = 531441.

So the total you want is $1 + (531441 - 3)/6 = 88574$

Comment: Nice way to circumvent Stirling ! (+1)

Comment: @trueblueanil this method is only efficient for three boxes, where there is just one non-$3!$ case and no need for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Perhaps it can be extended to $4$ boxes, too, for small numbers, e.g. $6$ distinct toys in $4$ boxes would be $1+31+\frac{(4^6 - 1\cdot4 -31\cdot{12})}{4!}$

Comment: @trueblueanil Nice. yes $4$ boxes isn't too bad, and you can generalize the $6$ to $n$ immediately. But each single increase in the number of boxes adds another correction term of increasing complexity. A general formula for $k$ boxes and $n$ toys using this idea might just end up being a recursive definition of those Sterling numbers (about which I know nothing).

Comment: Strange that I had not only understood, but developed a workable extension to $4$ boxes, and on coming back after an year or so, had totally forgotten the logic of it !

Comment: @trueblueanil It happens to me all the time, and more often as I get older ... 